# Modified cumulative sum of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, numbers, cumulative-sum

I want to create new list according cumulative sums of numbers in a list. Input is ideal - can be splitting to subset, sum of each subset is equal. Length of subset is not equal. Number of subset is input.

Each subset of output represents increment integers `[0,1,2,3,...]`, which replace original input. Quantity of integers is number of subsets.

**Example:**

```
number of subsets = 2   

input = [1, 4, 5]
#cumsum = [1, 5, 10]
subsets = [1,5], [10]
output-subsets = [0,0], [1]
output = [0, 0, 1]
```

**Example1:**

```
number of subsets = 4

input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6]
#cumsum = [1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 17, 18, 24]
subsets = [1,3,6], [10, 12],[17, 18], [24]
output-subsets = [0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3]
output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

```
number of subsets = 2

input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6]
#cumsum = [1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 17, 18, 24]
subsets = [1, 3, 6, 10, 12],[17, 18, 24]
output-subsets = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]
output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I try modified [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list):

```
def changelist(lis, t):
    total = 0

    s = sum(lis)
    subset = s/t

    for x in lis:
        total += x
        i= 1
        if(total <= subset):
            i = 0
        yield i


#changelist([input array], number of subset)    
print list(changelist([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6], 4))
```

but only first subset is correct:

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I think `numpy.array_split` is problematic [strange behaviour of numpy array_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165141/strange-behaviour-of-numpy-array-split).

I would really love any kind of explanation or help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your first block with sums is unclear.  I have no idea why the lists shown on the right hand side of each line are associated with the sums.  This statement also needs elaboration: "Each subset of output represents increment integers, which replace original input:."  particularly, what are the "increment integers"?

Comment: increment integers - I think that can be incremented e.g.[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5...] = 6 subsets if number of subset is higher

Comment: Your question is very unclear,  where does `numpy.array_split` fit into iit?

Comment: NumPy's array_split splits into subsets with equal length.

Comment: I agree that the question is not very clear. If it's just about reproducing the output: `(numpy.cumsum(input)-1)/6`

Comment: I try to clear question by examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
def changelist (l, t):
  subset = sum(l) / t
  current, total = 0, 0
  for x in l:
    total += x
    if total > subset:
      current, total = current + 1, x
    yield current
```

Examples:

```
>>> list(changelist([1, 4, 5], 2))
[0, 0, 1]
>>> list(changelist([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6], 4))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> list(changelist([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6], 2))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

How does it work?

- `current` stores the "id" of the current subset, `total` the sum of the current subset.
- For each element `x` in your initial list `l`, you add its value to the current `total`, if this `total` is greater than the expected sum of each subset (`subset` in my code), then you know that you are in the next subset (`current = current + 1`) and you "reset" the total of the current subset to the actuel element (`total = x`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NumPy` here after converting the `input` to an array for a vectorized solution, assuming `N` as the number of subsets, as listed here -

```
def modified_cumsum(input,N):
    A = np.asarray(input).cumsum()
    return np.append(False,np.in1d(A,(1+np.arange(N))*A[-1]/N))[:-1].cumsum()
```

Sample runs -

```
In [31]: N = 2  #number of subsets
    ...: input = [1, 4, 5]
    ...: 

In [32]: modified_cumsum(input,N)
Out[32]: array([0, 0, 1])

In [33]: N = 4  #number of subsets
    ...: input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6]
    ...: 

In [34]: modified_cumsum(input,N)
Out[34]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])

In [35]: N = 2  #number of subsets
    ...: input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6]
    ...: 

In [36]: modified_cumsum(input,N)
Out[36]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Is Numpy faster than pure python (Holt solution) for this kind of thing?, +1

Comment: @jezrael Conversion to a numpy array seems to be the bottleneck here. Other than that, it should be quite efficient.